# SVN branch compare

Tags: svn, branch, diff, branching-and-merging

How do I compare one branch with another? I want to compare a branch with the latest revision in trunk.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could start with:

```
svn diff http://REPOS/trunk http://REPOS/branches/B
```

(Where `http://REPOS` is your repository path including the parents of `trunk` and `branches`.)

This will print a large quantity of text, including all the textual changes but not the binary changes except to say where and when they occurred.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer led me to this http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html which explains how to do the same with TortoiseSVN

Comment: Shorthand -> `svn diff ^/trunk ^/branches/B`

Comment: Is there a way to hide the inner diff part? That means to only show revision, author, date, file list.

Comment: to learn REPOS write 'svn info'

Answer (score 20):

If you are just looking for high level of what files are different and do not want to see all the contents, use:

`svn diff ^/trunk ^/branches/dev --summarize`

(This compares trunk and dev branch)

Comment: For me in Linux I have to use escapes: `svn diff \^/[SUBPROJECT]/develop \^/[SUBPROJECT]/feature/myfeature/`

Answer (score 7):

I usually check out the two branches (or the branch and the trunk) into directories.
Then I use a graphical tool like Kompare or similar (depending on your preferences, operating system,...).
This is really helpful for me when I need to perform complex merges.

Answer (score 6):

As lack of reputation won't let me add this as a comment against an existing answer, I'm having to add it as a separate one.

A useful option to `svn diff` for me was `--ignore-properties`. My two branches had ended up identical code wise, but with different merge histories.

Using `--ignore-properties` allowed me to prove to myself that this was the case, without wading through the large quantity of "svn:mergeinfo" property changes.

Comment: Upvote to let you comment against existing answers. I feel you. This site is not good for people that do not know how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the info guys, I would add something to improve the readability of the diff results.If you used:
svn diff svn://url:9090/branches/PRD_0002 svn://url:9090/branches/TST_0003 >svn_diff_filename.txt

You can use:
findstr "Index:" C:\path\svn_diff_filename.txt >svn_diff_file_list.txt

That will bring you a readable list of files that have any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [post from Murray Cumming](http://www.murrayc.com/blog/permalink/2007/01/25/subversion-diff-between-branches/) which describes the non-obvious process:

- Discover the revision numbers: You need to know the revision numbers of the latest versions in each of the branches. It looks like svn log is the only way to do that.
- cd into one of the branch directories, such as trunk.
- Supply the revision numbers to the svn diff command: `svn diff -r123:145`

Comment: Won't this just tell you what's changed in `trunk` since the last commit to the branch? Apologies if I'm missing something - it's getting late here...

Comment: You don't need to look for the latest revision number in each branch: simply use `HEAD`. But this isn't what the OP was asking for -- he wanted to compare between his branch and trunk, not between two revisions in the same branch.

Answer (score 0):

To diff between two revisions of a branch:

```
svn diff -r rLATEST:rOLD
```

Use `svn log` to get the different revisions. Use can limit the number of revisions in the log using `svn log -l 5`. only the last 5 revisions will be shown.